# Crystal Reports: different results from distinctcount

Tags: crystal-reports, distinct-values

I work in an educational environment, and am building a report to count the number of course completions. Part of this is creating groups that filter by course managing organization.

Everything goes fine if I simply create a date field in the group and summarize it by distinctcount - I get the correct number of course completions by completion date. (I have a resource to independently verify this.) However, I also need to create a formula that will, eventually, calculate the average number of course sessions conducted per year.

With that in mind, I have tried to create a formula and insert it into the group, but every time I do this I get a completely incorrect number - it's a count of every single completion date, regardless of if it's distinct or not or even if it's in the single organization.

I've tried the following as a forumla:

```
Distinctcount({*data source*.*completion date field*})
```

and

```
whileprintingrecords;
Distinctcount({*data source*.*completion date field*})
```

and

```
numbervar sessions;
whileprintingrecords;
sessions:=distinctcount({*data source*.*completion date field*})
```

None of these work - they give the grand total of course completions.

I also tried whilereadingrecords, but it errors out on me and says "This function cannot be used because it must be evaluated later."

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Check if I am understanding correctly. It correctly counts by date (distinct). But now you need to count by year. Is it correct? If so, where is the "year" in the formulas? Would be enough to write: Distinctcount(year({*data source*.*completion date field*}))?

Comment: No, I will eventually need year as a criteria, but for now I just want to get the same result from the formula as from the summary.